# ObjectContext disposed also in opened context of EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dispose

I have this method for creating `DataTable`:

```
private DataTable toDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var tb = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        using (var context = new MyEntity())
        {
            PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[props.Length];
                for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }

                tb.Rows.Add(values);
            }
        }
       return tb;

    }
```

but it give me this error in second `foreach`:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

since I opened my EF's `context`;why again this error occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IEnumerable<T>` that you are passing into `toDataTable<T>()` has not been realized yet. The context of `items` is already disposed. You have forgotten a `ToList()` in the calling code.

Comment: Is your mean using method like this:`DataTable dt=toDataTable(myItems.ToList());`?

Comment: That will not work. If my answer is correct, it means that `myItems` is defined earlier in the code, I'm assuming that you've used the same `using` pattern as this problem code. If so, you will need to realize (materialize/execute) your LINQ query inside the `using` block. So in your code where you initially assign the value to `myItems` is where you would add `.ToList()`. Even in the function call to `toDataTable<T>` it is too late (otherwise you would not receive this error in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

If `items` originates from `EntityFramework` as well then it may be the culprit--it's Context may have closed.

Do you know which line the exception originates from?

Comment: Since that's where the `items` parameter is first used it's most likely that your issue is with enumerating that collection.  You could replace your whole method with a simple `items.ToList()` to verify this

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the `items` collection contains entities from EF. Those items originally belonged to an `ObjectContext`, which apparently was closed before you passed them into this method. Opening a brand new context doesn't help because that's not the context that these items belong to.

When you use reflection on one of these entities, it's likely attempting to lazily access a navigation property of the entity, which would require a database trip, but since the context that the entity belongs to is gone, that database trip cannot happen.

You can reattach the item to the new context, then this should work:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    context.Attach(item);
    ... // now your item is attached to a live context again, and it
        // can hit the database
}
```

This is assuming you want to lazily load this - if you want to eagerly load and avoid the second database hit, you'd need to [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it when you retrieve the item from the database in the first place.

Comment: Does this effect speed seriously?

Comment: If you lazily load each item, then it has to contact the database server every time. So if you have 100 items, each with 3 navigation properties, a lazy loaded method would have 300 roundtrips to the database, while an eager one would have 1 large one. In that case, 1 large one would easily be faster, but it's going to depend on your scenario - lazy-loaded has plenty of advantages too, like not retrieving things you don't actually need.

Comment: But I think Keith's answer is more likely - if you're getting the exception on the `foreach` itself, then it's probably his. If your exception is happening on the `GetValue` line, then it's probably mine.

Comment: I used `foreach (var item in items.ToList())`; and again same error in same line!

Comment: I also used `DataTable dt=toDataTable(myItems.ToList());` (calling method with open context) but same error in this line of code!

Comment: You'd need to edit your question to include the method where you're calling `toDataTable`.